# parse the dataset string to the object

Tags: c#, database

I am receiving data in dataset form, which i have stored in a string.
Data is coming in this form:

How can i bind this string to my object.

Comment: that format is called xml

Comment: Parse the data into XML and extract the Name element

Comment: i m bit new in this, can u suggest some good link or any code would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to "Serialization/Deserialization".

Here is a good [Exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Doc on msdn' website : [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)